# How to find $\lim a(n+1)/a(n)$ for this recursion?

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

Let $a(0)=c$ be a given positive real number.
Let $P_k(n)$ be given integer polynomials of $n$ of degree at most $6$.
Now consider the recursion equation :

$P_5(n)a(n+4)+P_4(n)a(n+3)+P_3(n)a(n+2)+P_2(n)a(n+1)+P_1(n)a(n)+P_0(n)=0$

How to compute $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}  a(n+1)/a(n)$ ?

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe the limit exists?

Comment: Yes I read an example once ?? Assuming that was correct.

Comment: If all the $P_i$ are zero, then $a(n)$ can be anything, so it is reasonable to assume that you mean "some $P_i\ne0$" or "all the $P_i$ are nonzero".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If** the limit $r$ of $a(n+1)/a(n)$ exists and **if** the polynomials $P_k$ all have the same degree with leading coefficients $c_k$ **except** $P_0$ which is of a lower degree, then $r$ solves
$$
c_5r^4+c_4r^3+c_3r^2+c_2r+c_1=0.
$$
But these are a lot of *ifs*...

Comment: Are those ifs $=$ iffs ?
I assumed what you wrote , but how do we prove that ?

Comment: I wrote IF because I meant IF. Had I meant IFF, I would have written IFF. In other words, I write IFF iff I mean IFF.

Comment: Yes but then can you specify the exact conditions ?
And how do you prove the equation you wrote ?
My apologies for the if question.

Comment: Divide everything by $a(n)$ and keep only the equivalent of each term.

Comment: I do not understand.

Comment: For example, what would be a simple equivalent of $P_5(n)a(n+4)/a(n)$ when $n\to\infty$?

Comment: I guess $P_5(n) r^4$. Though I hesitate. How do you know you can drop the nonleading coefficients and the powers of $n$ ?

Comment: Something even simpler: $P_5(n)r^4$ behaves like...

Comment: I do not see how that reduces to $c_5 r^4$ ?

Comment: That does not. But $P_5(n)=c_5n^d+$some lower degree terms, hence...

Comment: Now offense and your answer is correct. But I still do not get it. These steps seem handwaving to me although I guess they are correct.

Comment: Do not worry about the steps, there is not one iota of *handwaving* in them. // By the way, what about clarifying the hypotheses of the exercise?

Comment: Hypothese ?? What are the next steps ?

Comment: Did you read my answer at all? You might have noticed some [hypotheses](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypotheses#English) there, which may be or may be not necessary before one can state a result. These are not in your question. Why? Do you think the result holds quite generally?

Comment: OK. Thanks ! I gave it consideration again and understand how you got the equation.
However say the polynomial(*) has 2 roots with a difference smaller than 0.00001 how do I know what root to choose ?
(* maybe for this degree 4 question this is not possible but it is for recursions of higher degree )

Comment: This might depend on the initial conditions (which, by the way, should involve $(a(0),a(1),a(2),a(3))$ and not only $a(0)$).

Comment: Yes I guessed so. But is there a way to formally compute it from the initial conditions ? Without many iterations like going till $a(100)$ ?

Comment: Hello ? Still considering to answer my comment ? Thanks for the help sofar btw.